# How to Ignore .aux files in Geany's Find in Files?

Tags: ide, geany

I would like to have some sort of ignorelist where I can add files which I do not want to search. You find `Find in Files* by second clicking Left-column in *Documents* view/tab.

My output for steeldriver's aswers

```
--exclude='*.aux' --exclude='*.bib' --exclude='*.log' 
--exclude='*.svg' --exclude='*.blg'
```

---

How can you ignore. aux files in Geany's *Find in Files*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geany appears to use `grep` under the hood for searching within files, and it provides an **Extra options:** field to pass additional arguments to the grep command. Hence you should simply be able to add `--exclude='*.aux'` in the box provided:

[image]

```
--exclude=GLOB
       Skip  files  whose  base  name  matches  GLOB  (using   wildcard
       matching).   A  file-name  glob  can  use  *,  ?,  and [...]  as
       wildcards, and \ to quote  a  wildcard  or  backslash  character
       literally.
```

See `man grep` for additional usage options.

Comment: So to exclude many `grep --exclude='*.aux,*.bib'`, right? I think Geany saves the Extra options there for the later use.

Comment: @Masi I don't believe grep currently supports pattern lists for the `--exclude` option; however you could supply multiple patterns like `--exclude='*.aux' --exclude='*.bib'`. Alternatively, use the `--exclude-from=file` facility. Check the grep manpages for your system. Yes the selection does appear to get saved in the geany.conf file (parameters `fif_extra_options` and `fif_use_extra_options`).